# Url Rewrite does not support xml extension

Tags: php, xml, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the following file from `.php` to `.xml` but it doesn't work! It seems that the xml extension is not supported, because when I try to rewrite to .xmml or .another_extension it works perfectly.

here is my .htaccess code :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.xml$ $1.php
```

Comment: you are now rewriting _from_ `.xml` _to_ `.php`.

Comment: what part exectly "is not working"? What do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: @Jeff i want to rewrite a php file to xml one, 

exemple: from `http://example.com/file.php` to `http://example.com/file.xml`

as i said when i try to change the `.xml` extension to any others extensions it works perfectly 

exemple: `http://example.com/file.php` to `http://example.com/file.xmlaaa`

Comment: then just swap it: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.xml`

Comment: _" i want to rewrite a php file to xml one"_ - now you say that's not what you need. I don't know what you need now, so I can't help.

Comment: @Jeff sorry i meant: " not working already try it, when i swap it will redirect from `xml` to `php` and it's not what i need "